# Defining the smallest integer $k$ such that every graph of minimum degree at least $k$ contains a perfect matching?

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I am having some difficulty with how to think about this question. Graph theory questions like this are not my strong point.

Let $n\geq2$ be an even integer. Define $f(n)$ to be the smallest integer $k$ such that every graph $G$ on $n$ vertices with minimum degree at least $k$ contains a perfect matching. Determine $f(n)$ and justify your answer.

To begin with, I thought that complete bipartite graph on n vertices, where $n=2k$ (so as to ensure $k$ vertices in each independent set), would definitely contain a perfect matching. Therefore, $f(n)=\frac{n}{2}$. Can this answer be improved upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way to think about the problem: just because a complete bipartite graph $K_{n/2,n/2}$ has a perfect matching, and satisfies $k = \frac n2$, doesn't mean that *every* graph with minimum degree $\frac n2$ would have a perfect matching.

You should think of it this way: you tell me a $k$, and I try as hard as I can to come up with a graph with minimum degree $k$, but no perfect matching, because I'm mean and don't like perfect matchings. You like perfect matchings, so you want to find a $k$ such that no matter *what* I do, I can't come up with such a graph.

---

If you want to take a moment to try to think about the problem again from this perspective, here is the point to pause reading.

---

Specific examples are good for the other direction. An unbalanced complete bipartite graph $K_{n/2-1, n/2+1}$ has minimum degree $\frac n2 - 1$, so if your choice of $k$ is $\frac n2 - 1$ or less, I can give you $K_{n/2-1,n/2+1}$, and you won't be able to find a perfect matching. So $f(n)$ must be *at least* $\frac n2$.

In this case, we do actually have $f(n) = \frac n2$, but we need a different argument: one that applies to *all* graphs with minimum degree $\frac n2$. A theorem you may be familiar with is Dirac's theorem: that any graph with minimum degree $\frac n2$ has a Hamiltonian cycle. If you can find a Hamiltonian cycle, then taking every other edge of that cycle will produce a perfect matching. This completes the proof.